# How to find Android video decoder UV plane pixel stride using ndk

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, yuv

When decoding video using NDK on Android, on some devices I get YUV image with UV plane pixel stride 2 (UVUVU...) and on others I get 4 (UUVVUUVV...). In bot cases decoder reported image format is "21". How can I find pixel stride of UV plane?
My experimental conclusion is that Android 8+ gives pixel stride 4, and Android 7 pixel stride 2, but is there a way to be sure?

Comment: If you call `AMediaFormat_getInt32` with the key `"color-format"`, does it return the same value on all OS versions (if it returns anything at all)?

Comment: This is what I get with "AMediaFormat_toString":  "mime: string(video/raw), stride: int32(1920), slice-height: int32(1088), color-format: int32(21), image-data: data, crop: unknown(9), hdr-static-info: data, width: int32(1920), height: int32(1088)}."

Comment: I was wrong when I sad UVUV vs UUVVUUVV. It is actualy UVUV... vs U(0)U(s/2)V(0)V(s/2)U(1)U(s/2+1)V(1)V(s/2+1) where "s" is size of UV plane...
The main problem is that in both cases I get image-format 21.

Comment: `U(0)U(s/2)…` - can you post the image? This sounds weird. Note that usually, the output format of decoder is dictated by the input.

Comment: @AlexCohn Video was created using camera2 API and same AMediaCodec used for decoding. Camera produces nice UVUVUV... format and encoder excepts this with no problem (hmm... or does he?). When I decode it using AMediaCodec I have to do this: 

 for (int i=0; i<frame.plane_UV.size/2; i++) {
        uv_ptr_dst[i] = *uv_ptr_src++;
        uv_ptr_dst[i+frame.plane_UV.size/2] = *uv_ptr_src++;
 }
to make it UVUVUV...
I dont have image right now, but it is consistent with the code above.

Comment: I think your loop builds (the chroma part of) YUV420 planar from YUV420 semiplanar. `frame.plane_UV.size` is `frame.width*frame.height/2`, isn't it? Then, your `uv_ptr_src[0]` is **U** for pixel `(0,0)`, and `uv_ptr_src[1]` is **V** for same pixel. The loop puts `frame.width*frame.height/4` **U** values to `uv_ptr_dst`, and `frame.width*frame.height/4` **U** values to `uv_ptr_dst + frame.width*frame.height/4`.

Comment: Actually, it puts src[0] to dst[0] and src[1] to dst[UV_size/2] and so on... But this is beside the point of the question. The problem is that AMediaForamt gives image-format 21 in both cases, so I don't know when to use this and when not to...